# Eclipse: What is the keyboard shortcut for searching for a file (given specific keywords in it as a search criteria) in a particular folder?

Tags: java, eclipse

In Eclipse, what is the keyboard shortcut for searching for a file (given specific keywords in it as a search criteria) in a particular folder?

Comment: just as an aside - as this Q relates to using software, it *might* be better suited for superuser.com. personally i think it's fine either here or there but you might get a better answer on su.

Comment: @jammypeach: I beg to differ, as Eclipse is strictly a programming tool. Even the SO-faq states that *We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question generally covers... ...software tools commonly used by programmers... ...then you’re in the right place to ask your question!*

Comment: yep, as I said I don't think it's wrong to post it here, just that the OP might get a better answer on SU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select your folder in which you want to search, then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> and select the `Selected resources` radiobutton. The search will only be executed for the selected folder. You can even select multiple folders or files before pressing the shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

Click on the folder you want to search and then CTRL + SHIFT + H.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, I would like to put the Q other way...I want to know the keyboard shortcut for searching for all files (say *.java files) in a particular folder (say folder with name 'Abc') which have particular keyword (say keyword "return 0;").

This functionality will be similar to what we get by doing Ctrl+H (but, Ctrl+H searches in the workspace or specified working set). I want to search in particular folder by clicking on the folder in Navigator.

Comment: I don't think is possible searching for folders that aren't in the workspace. =/

Comment: @ user1242756, I am talking about the folder in workspace only, but is there any option that lets me search for a java file that contains "return 0;" in specific folder 'Abc' (which is in the workspace)? (The key here is that I don't want to search in whole workspace as it will be a waste of time and I will get unwanted results too).

Comment: That's what I meant in the first answer.
1 - select the folder you want to search in the workspace
2 - hold CTRL+H 
3 - on the option 'Search in' select 'selected resources' (default is 'workspace').

Answer (score 1):

The keyboard shortcut is : Ctrl + Shift + R